# Configuring Web application using WiX and use the application in an already present App Pool

Tags: iis, wix, application-pool, wix3.8, vs-web-application-project

I have a web application with .NET 4.5.2 that should be used by already existing app pool with .NET 4.0 in the IIS. Can it be configured in WiX itself and how to host the application in the existing app pool

Answer (score 0):

You can use iis Extension. http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/iis/website.html

Try to follow [This Blog](http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/2013/10/create-an-installer-for-website-with-wix-part-3/).